# Squid SSL transparent proxy

Tags: ssl-certificate, squid

It just doesn't work, does it?

Firefox OK after installing the `.pem` file, but other applications not working.

Converted the `.pem` file to a `.crt` using

```
# openssl x509 -outform der -in myCA.pem -out myCA.crt
```

and installed it as a *Trusted Root Certification Autnorities* in  `certlm` but still lots of things not working: Outlook, Teams, GoogleDrive,...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be very unreliable.

This is the configuration (from https://elatov.github.io/2019/01/using-squid-to-proxy-ssl-sites/) that's got Squid working. I have no idea why -- I just got lucky.

```
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
ssl_bump splice all
```

with

- the `.pem` in the browser as an *Authority*, and
- the `.crt` in Windows as a *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*.

For the exceptions the best approach is to not send them to Squid in the first place. Using the `-d` flag with a domain name in the `iptables` command simply resolves it to an IP address at the time the command therefore it's better to maintain an `ipset` that `iptables` can reference.

Here is my script for maintaining my `ipset` with the domains in a text file.
The idea is that this can be run as a `cron` job to pick up new domains and update the map to IP addresses.

```
#!/bin/sh

## Bypass Squid

ipset -L no-proxy >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Creating ipset: no-proxy."
        ipset create no-proxy hash:ip
fi

ipset flush no-proxy

if [ -f "/etc/squid/no-proxy-iptables.txt" ]; then
        for domain in $(cat /etc/squid/no-proxy-iptables.txt); do
                for address in $( dig a $domain +short | grep -P -e '^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$' ); do
                        echo $domain " -> " $address
                        ipset add no-proxy $address
                done
        done
else
        echo "File doess not exist: /etc/squid/no-proxy-iptables.txt"
fi
```

And here is my firewall script:

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F # Does NOT flush everything! Hence the other three commands.
iptables -X

# Squid: exceptions
ipset -L no-proxy >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Using ipset: no-proxy."
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -m set --match-set no-proxy dst -j ACCEPT
fi

# Squid: HTTP
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.31:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128

# Squid: HTTPS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.31:3129
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129

# IP masquerade

iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i br0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s6f1u2 -j MASQUERADE

# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

You seem to be able to get a good guess at what domains to bypass by keeping an eye on the *network* tab in the browser dev tools.